# Custom Email templates breaks some times

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have created a 'new order' email template. As well as I have updated the files in the following folder by moving them into the my custom theme.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email

When I placed an order Sometimes it is showing 'html' tags on the email body. (See the attached images). 
If I resend the same email again from the admin backend I am getting the correct content. I can't figure out why this is happening. Any help highly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

I am using Mangeto 2.3.0 CE

Comment: try to recreate from admin and check html

Comment: i think you missing html end tag for ex:- <p></p>